# Disable time in datteimpicker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I  am using [`bootstrap datetimepicker`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I want to disable the time. Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#checkout').datetimepicker({  
     format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'   ,
     useCurrent: false           
});
```

`pickTime:false` -Shows error to me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify  `pickTime:false`

If your format is

```
 format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
```

It will by default remove the time part.

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/gkqc2tw2/

Comment: showing me the white space at bottom of picker which is clickable but with no functionality

Comment: It may have been because of plugin version difference. Please update your "bootstrapdatetime" picker plugin.. And If you can please create JS Fiddle of your code so that we can have a look at problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minView` option here like

```
jQuery('#checkout').datetimepicker({  
     format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
     minView: 1
});
```